# CSS: 3 or 4 columns depending on device orientation

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dynamic

I want to achieve the following: I have a total of 12 divs, inside one div.
Depending on the media query (tablet portrait, tablet landscape, mobile portrait, mobile landscape etc..),I want to show three columns with four divs inside or four columns with three divs inside.

This should be the end results:

**3 columns, four divs per column**
[image]

**4 columns, three divs per column**
[image]

I'm having problems with figuring out an way to achieve this with CSS only.

```
<div className="cb-Categorie-Wrapper">
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Fictie"><span className="label">Fictie</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Thrillers-spanning" ><span className="label">Thrillers en spanning</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Romantiek"><span className="label">Romantiek</span></div>

    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Kinderen-YA"><span className="label">Kinderen en YA</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Non-fictie"><span className="label">Non-fictie</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Reizen"><span className="label">Reizen</span></div>

    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Mens-ontwikkeling"><span className="label">Mens en ontwikkeling</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Management"><span className="label">Management</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Educatief"><span className="label">Educatief</span></div>

    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Engels"><span className="label">Engelse boeken</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Anderstalig"><span className="label">Andere anderstalige boeken</span></div>
    <div className="cb-Categorie" id="categorie-Non-books"><span className="label">Non-books</span></div>
</div>
```

I enclosed every three divs with an wrapper div that would be an block, with float:left (see picture: 4 columns, three divs per column), this made four columns next to eachother.

But now the wish is to have the columns as picture 1 (3 columns, four divs).

I am able to use Bootstrap3 if that's helpful.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but where does `className` come from? it should just be `class="..."`

Comment: Sorry, I'm using react, where class should be defined as className.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info and clarification. Didn't think of this :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.column-example {
    column-count: 4;
column-rule-style: solid;
column-rule-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-example">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use vendor prefixes in production code. They are experimental and not ready for prime time. They are also not needed in current browsers.

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the question: Which is about providing different layouts depending on device orientation.

Comment: with this you can easily achieve that and in media query you can change your count as per your need [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) reference here

Comment: @Quentin please check the link and the browser compatibility it is working on modern browsers even IE10. You can remove the vendor prefixes

Comment: Can you explain to me what the column count does? does it make columns of the div inside the wrapper? I don't need to support < IE10, so that's fine.

@Quentin I have media queries written already and I understand how to use the column-count in the different orientations.

Comment: The column-count property specifies the number of columns an element should be divided into. And like you said you want it just with the CSS then this will help you, also if you want you can increase the div as well it will work accordingly only with column count you defined.

Comment: Is it possible to give the made column an background color or something?

Comment: you can give the borders not background colors, i have updated the snippet with borders you can check